# How to make my game of life continue to the next generation?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, conways-game-of-life

Main Class

```
package edu.bsu.cs121.mamurphy;

public class GameOfLifeMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            new GameOfLifeGUI();
            System.out.println();

        }

    }

}
```

Tester Class

```
package edu.bsu.cs121.mamurphy;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class tester extends JPanel

{
    final static int ROW = 25, COL = 75;
    final static char DOT = '.';
    static char[][] grid = new char[ROW + 2][COL + 2];
    static char[][] nextgrid = new char[ROW + 2][COL + 2];
    boolean sameFlag;
    boolean blankFlag;

    public static void init(char[][] grid, char[][] nextgrid) {
        for (int row = 0; row <= ROW + 1; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col <= COL + 1; col++) {
                grid[row][col] = DOT;
                nextgrid[row][col] = DOT;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void pause() {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread();
            Thread.sleep(1000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    public void begin() {
        init(grid, nextgrid);
        read(grid);
        repaint(); // calls paintComponent
        pause();
        while (sameFlag == true && blankFlag == false) {
            nextGen(grid, nextgrid);
        }
    }

    public static void read(char[][] grid) {
        Scanner world = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type the file name of the world you'd like to create.");
        String fileName = world.nextLine();
        {
            try {
                world = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Please insert a valid file name.");
            }
            for (int row = 1; row <= ROW; row++) {
                String s = world.next();
                for (int col = 1; col <= COL; col++) {
                    grid[row][col] = s.charAt(col - 1);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public void print(Graphics g) {
        int x, y;
        y = 20;
        for (int row = 1; row <= ROW; row++) {
            x = 20;
            for (int col = 1; col <= COL; col++) {
                g.drawString("" + grid[row][col], x, y);
                x = x + 7;
            }
            y = y + 15;
        }
    }

    public static int neighbors(char[][] grid, int r, int c) {
        // counts the # of closest neighbors that are X's
        int count = 0;
        for (int row = r - 1; row <= r + 1; row++) {
            for (int col = c - 1; col <= c + 1; col++) {
                if (grid[row][col] == 'X') {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (grid[r][c] == 'X') {
            count = count - 1;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void nextGen(char[][] grid, char[][] nextgrid) {
        for (int row = 1; row <= ROW; row++) {
            for (int col = 1; col <= COL; col++) {
                if (grid[row][col] == 'X') {
                    int count = 0;
                    {
                        if (grid[row][col - 1] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                        if (grid[row][col + 1] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                        if (grid[row - 1][col] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                        if (grid[row - 1][col - 1] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                        if (grid[row - 1][col + 1] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                        if (grid[row + 1][col - 1] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                        if (grid[row + 1][col] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                        if (grid[row + 1][col + 1] == 'X')
                            count = count + 1;
                    }

                    if (count == 2 || count == 3) {
                        nextgrid[row][col] = 'X';
                    } else
                        nextgrid[row][col] = DOT;
                }
                if (grid[row][col] == DOT) {
                    int count1 = 0;
                    {
                        if (grid[row][col - 1] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                        if (grid[row][col + 1] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                        if (grid[row - 1][col] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                        if (grid[row - 1][col - 1] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                        if (grid[row - 1][col + 1] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                        if (grid[row + 1][col - 1] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                        if (grid[row + 1][col] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                        if (grid[row + 1][col + 1] == 'X')
                            count1 = count1 + 1;
                    }
                    if (count1 == 3)
                        nextgrid[row][col] = 'X';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void copy(char[][] grid, char[][] nextgrid) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COL + 1; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = nextgrid[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isEmpty(char[][] grid, char[][] nextgrid) {
        boolean blankFlag = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COL + 1; j++) {
                if (grid[i][j] != DOT) {
                    blankFlag = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return blankFlag;
    }

    public static boolean isSame(char[][] grid, char[][] nextgrid) {
        boolean sameFlag = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COL + 1; j++) {
                if (grid[i][j] == nextgrid[i][j]) {
                    sameFlag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return sameFlag;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);// erases panel Contents
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        if (sameFlag == false && blankFlag == false) {
            print(g);
        } else {
            if (sameFlag == true) {
                g.drawString("This worldis the same as the last one.", 10, 250);
            }
            if (blankFlag == true) {
                g.drawString("Everyone died. Good job.", 10, 250);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

GUI Class

```
package edu.bsu.cs121.mamurphy;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

//

public class GameOfLifeGUI extends JFrame {

    public GameOfLifeGUI() {
        super("Game of Life");
        setSize(600, 445);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        tester test1 = new tester();
        test1.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        panel.add(test1);
        setContentPane(panel);
        setVisible(true);
        Temp one = new Temp(test1);
        one.start();
    }

    class Temp extends Thread {
        tester anim;

        public Temp(tester anim) {
            this.anim = anim;

        }

        public void run()// for each instance of test begin will be executed
        {
            anim.begin();
        }
    }
}
```

Hi stackoverflow. I have been working on this game of life project for the last few days and I have hit one final wall in trying to finish it up. How do I make it proceed to the next generation?

I know for what I am required to do I need to ask the user if they wish to continue to the next generation or not. I know I need to use a scanner and then have a loop that checks to see what the user's input is, as well as a try catch to make sure the program doesn't crash if they type in anything that isn't what the program asks them to.

My only issue is that I do not know where to put this code at in my tester class (if that is actually where it needs to go).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Side notes on your code: class names should start uppercase. Using the `X` character to "remember" alive cells is a poor way of doing that. Ideally, you would be using an enum (or at least a boolean) as abstraction. For your question itself, I dont get your problem. You ask the user for input; then you configure the initial "matrix"; you put that on the screen; then you put in some "delay"; compute next, display next, "wait", ... and so on. Until the board is dead; or maybe until the user clicks on some button that you add to your UI.

Comment: My question is where in my tester class do I insert a scanner asking the user if they wish to continue to the next generation of life. They would type y to continue to the next generation, or n to not and end the program. I am not sure where the code should go and what the code should look like.

Comment: That simply does not make sense: either your application is "graphical"; or it is command line. Meaning: if you do "scan" / "println" on the command line; **or** (like in exclusive or) you pull up a panel and draw elements there. Decide which one to go for. If you decide for "UI" - then forget about having the user type stuff on the command line. Then add UI elements that ask for his input. As said: add two buttons to your panel; and that says "compute next generation", and one that says "quit" ... and implement the corresponding actions for them.

Comment: So then that changes my question. How do I go about adding that panel and those buttons as well as the code that goes with those buttons?

Comment: For that, you study tutorials out there? Why do expect people explaining stuff to you ... instead of doing some research first on your own?